# WordPress Ajax call not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have set up different AJAX calls in my WP site and everything works fine, except one specific AJAX call and only in Firefox.

I give below the details to reproduce the problem. It includes login credentials, but it is a WP test site and these are fake credentials, so don't worry, you can use it.

Go to https://responsive.knowledgeplaces.com

Login with credentials "aweb01" as userid and password.

Once connected, you will see different buttons. These are buttons for testing purposes.

For instance, you can click on the button "no lpId parameter", and you will see an error message.

All these button trigger AJAX calls on the server, and an alert message is displayed if some validation went wrong on the server.

All these buttons work fine and you will see the alert message on any browser, including Firefox.

There is another button "deconnexion" (logout) on the upper right side of the page.

When you click on this button, you are logged out from the site.

The button works fine on Chrome and IE, but not on Firefox.

Here is how it is implemented.

First, there is a javascript file with the following code:

```
$("a[href='/kps_logout']").on('click', function() {
    // check href symbolic URL
    jQuery.post(
    WP_AJAX_URL,
            {
                'action': 'kps_logout',
                'security': $("#kpcms-ajax-nonce").val()
            }
        );
        // redirect and deactivate default navigation
        window.location.href = $kps_Host + $kps_LoginPath;
return false;
});
```

Basically, I use a symbolic '/kps_logout' URL, and this JQuery code maps a logout function on any href with this link.

On the server, I have this code in the "functions.php" of my WordPress child theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_kps_logout', 'kps_logout' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_kps_logout', 'kps_logout' );
function kps_logout() {
    // security check
    check_ajax_referer( 'kpcms-ajax-nonce', 'security' );
    // logout user and die
    wp_logout();
    die ();
}
```

Once again, works perfectly in Chrome and IE, not if Firefox.

If I activate the network dev tools, it sounds the AJAX call is not even performed in Firefox, while I can see it in Chrome and IE.

On the "no lpId parameter" button, I can see the AJAX call in all browsers, and it works fine on all browsers. And it is implemented exactly the same way.

I have cleared the cache of Firefox but it does not help.

So if you can help me on this, it would be great!

Comment: `window.location.href = $kps_Host + $kps_LoginPath;` should be put in the `post` callback, to guaranty the AJAX call is executed before the page navigation takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript should be :

```
$("a[href='/kps_logout']").on('click', function() {
    // check href symbolic URL
    jQuery.post(
    WP_AJAX_URL,
            {
                'action': 'kps_logout',
                'security': $("#kpcms-ajax-nonce").val()
            }, 
        function(response){
        // redirect and deactivate default navigation
        var redirectTo = response;
         window.location.href = redirectTo ;
        });

return false;
});
```

And Your PHP should something like

```
<?php 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_kps_logout', 'kps_logout' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_kps_logout', 'kps_logout' );
function kps_logout() {
    // security check
    check_ajax_referer( 'kpcms-ajax-nonce', 'security' );
    // logout user and die
    wp_logout();

    echo  get_bloginfo("home");
    die ();
}   

?>
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you.
I go with imtheman answer which works fine.
And yes indeed, the redirect needed to be performed after the AJAX call.